# strangely felt connected

Tags: meaning, adverbs

a. She strangely felt connected to this man she had just met.

Does this mean

1. It was strange that She felt connected to this man she had just met.

or

2. She felt connected to this man she had just met in a strange way.

?

I think either is possible, but (1) is more likely.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the source of the sentence?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't 'She felt **strangely connected** to this man she had just met', which is a familiar cliché, esspecially in bad romantic fiction?

Comment: She strangely felt connected to x. is fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it can be interpreted as (1).
Bear in mind that when someone meets another person, it is unusual to feel very connected, because you don't know him well enough to do so. Despite this, she did, so that's why the word *strangely* is used.
In other words, what *strangely* wants to convey is the unusual or unexpected nature of what the woman is feeling.

Comment: she met in a strange way? You didn't catch that, right? No worries.

Comment: @Lambie, I apologize if I have posted an inaccurate answer, since I am a non native speaker. Could you ellaborate on what idea are you trying to convey?

Comment: Please do not apologize. She felt strangely connected to x. is what we can say here.

Comment: Uhm, indeed, it's an unnatural word order. I probably overlooked it because my native language allows subject ellipsis, so my brain read it as something like "Strangely, (she) felt connected..." (This should be a grammatical sentence, right?)

Comment: Yes, **Strangely, she felt connected to x" OR She felt strangely connected to x. are slightly different in meaning. :)